# FLEX/AS3 - Save XML to new file?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I've got an XML file that I open and do some changes with inside my app, and I need to be able to save it out to a new file.

Now I'm using this code to save it to the same file:

```
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(myOpenXML, FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeUTFBytes(myXMLString);
fs.close();
```

If I trace myXMLString I get proper formatting (new line for every object in the XML), but when I save it out, everything ends up on one line.. How come?
And I want to save to a new file, how do I do that? (using save dialog box).

I'm using Flash Builder. Flex, AS3, AIR..

Thanks a lot for your time and help ;)

Comment: FileStream is for save to file , You have to create new File (flash.filesystem.File) , change URL ( by browse or resolve old file and change name ) and save binary data . To write XML to file use fs.writeUTF();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer a part of your question, about saving to a new file using Save Dialog box. You will be using a [`FileReference`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) to do this.

Here is a snippet I copied from [this article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/filereference_class_as3.html) which I suggest you read.

```
private var _loadFile:FileReference;

private function startLoadingFile():void
{
    _loadFile = new FileReference();
    _loadFile.addEventListener(Event.SELECT, selectHandler);
    var fileFilter:FileFilter = new FileFilter("Images: (*.jpeg, *.jpg, *.gif, *.png)", "*.jpeg; *.jpg; *.gif; *.png");
    _loadFile.browse([fileFilter]);
}
```

Comment: in AIR more usefull would be use File class , dont You think ?

Comment: Yes absolutely. `File` class extends the `FileReference` class. Sorry I was under the impression that this was an AIR app. :)

Comment: and File have browseForSave() method , that might be very usefull in Stian case .